# Update a ListView's children from an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have a `ListView` that is populated with `TaskView` objects using a `TaskAdapter` (that extends `ArrayAdapter<Task>`. Each `TaskView` comes with populated with a [`ProgressWheel`](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel) and two `TextView`s for status updates.

I also have subclass of `AsyncTask` whose job it is to monitor the progress of the ongoing task. Whenever it receive a progress notification, it passes it on to the `onProgressUpdate()` method. The `onProgressUpdate()` method is supposed to update the view in the list based on the `TaskEvent` that it receives.

I'm having trouble getting the `TaskView` that corresponds to the `Task` object that was added using the list's `TaskAdapter`.

Here is the relevant class:

```
public class ProgressMonitor extends AsyncTask<Void, TaskEvent, Void> {
    private Task task;
    private TaskView view;
    private ListView list;

    public ProgressMonitor(Task task, ListView list) {
        this.task = task;
        // I know leaving unchecked casts are a bad practice, but this was a temporary fix
        ArrayAdapter<Task> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Task>) list.getAdapter();
        adapter.add(task);
        this.view = // get view from adapter that corresponds to task
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do stuff in background, send progress using publishProgress(TaskEvent)
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(TaskEvent... values) {
        TaskEvent e = values[0];

        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case SOME_STATUS:
                // update view, but view is null
                break;
            case DIFFERENT_STATUS:
                // update view in a different way, but view is still null
                break;
            // etc.
            default:
                Log.w(TAG, "No action for " + e.getAction());
        }
    }
}
```

The class is used like this:

```
Task task = // ...
new ProgressMonitor(task, list).execute();
```

Comment: you can use broadcast receiver, in onPostExecute register one broadcast and in onReceive refresh your adapter, or make your class as inner class and use `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. How would using a `BroadcaseReceiver` help if I'm not using `Intent`s?

Comment: whit `BroadcastReceiver` you can notify your class to do something.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add in `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` whenever you change the data displayed.

Comment: This is already being called by `ArrayAdapter` when I call `add(Task)`: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#171

Comment: By the way, this is not an actual answer, so it should be in the comments section of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for getting views of list you have to assign ListView list to your local object that is list
like this and set adapter to listview object then u will be abe to refresh the list in progress update
 public ProgressMonitor(Task task, ListView list) {
this.list = list; 
//you have to set apater to list view
list.setAdapter(Adptr);
}

@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(TaskEvent... values) {
        TaskEvent e = values[0];

        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case SOME_STATUS:
                // update view, but view is null

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case DIFFERENT_STATUS:
                // update view in a different way, but view is still null
                break;
            // etc.
            default:
                Log.w(TAG, "No action for " + e.getAction());
        }
    }
```